# Can any one tell me the issue of this function .. this function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    var c = confirm("Are You want to open Foortal.pk");
    if (c) {

        window.location.replace("http://www.google.com")

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});​
```

i don't know about problem

Comment: I don't think it is possible to redirect in unload handler.

Comment: Browsers block this for a reason.

Comment: possibilities available but i cant understand

Comment: a check for redirect on unload ... i've always done this in the php/asp.net controller ...

Comment: See my reply below Bruver! `:)`

Comment: one give me the code and code is working :)

Comment: Make sure you are grammatically correct as well:  Are you sure you want to open Foortal.pk

Answer (score 3):

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/FUXRF/

Read this ==> https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-onbefore-unload-and-page-redirect

This will work like a rocket `:)` I hope for everyone

**code**

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    var c = confirm("Are You want to open Foortal.pk");
    if (c) {
        alert(window.location);
       // window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
        window.parent.location = "http://www.google.com";
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});

$(window).trigger('unload');
​
```

Comment: This Code is perfect Thanks Friend

Answer (score 1):

```
window.parent.location ="http://www.google.com";
```

use that instead of

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Yo Scott man - I reckon you missed `parent` **rest see my demo below!** do this `window.parent.location` `:)` +1 anyways buddy.

Answer (score 0):

We do it in this way

```
   $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){
        return "Are you OK?";
    });
```

Try to

```
   $(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){
        var c = confirm("Are You want to open Foortal.pk");
        if (c) {

            window.location("http://www.google.com");

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: how can i redirect the page on checking ?

Comment: @climbage: checked now and the code `return "Are you OK?";` produces alert with text "Are you OK?"

Comment: work proper problem is that var c = confirm("Are You want to open Foortal.pk");
 this line is not working

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the ';' on

```
window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Yo, I reckon that is not the issue, `:)` use od location should resolve the issue, see the link and code below!